# Strage html code behavior

Tags: php, html

i have very strange problem:

my site engine uses php. when page created, i view it's HTML code (using broswer's menu "see source html") and i see this (i place here only important part of code):

```
<div class="main_page_blogs_post2_item1">

            <div><p><p>
    <div class="cblui_image_contaner_" align="center">
```

but REAL html code differs from source code - when i view this code using firebug, i see this code:

```
<div class="main_page_blogs_post2_item1">
<div>
<p></p>
<p> </p>
<div class="cblui_image_contaner_" align="center">
```

i mean that closing `</p>` tags are autoadded to html code and i d't know why.
i thought that it's javascript, but i try to reload page with javascript disabled - it not helps.
and i d't thik it's php's fault, cause source code is correct.

UPD:
i found out, that in my case 2 opening `<p>` tags and 2 closing `</p>` tags have been converted to `<p></p>` combination. All others `<p>` tags have not been affected.

What may it be?

Thanks

P.S. sorry for bad english :)

Comment: `p` tags can be left "open" as in your source code, however browsers render those tags left open with a closing tag, as reflected by firebug. Nothing to worry about - you might consider closing those `p` tags though yourself, for clarity.

Comment: they closes later in my code - i just put not all my code here, cause it too big. Browser changes both open and close tags to `<p></p>` combinatiom. Looks like browser d't found my closing `</p>` tags and autoclose opening `<p>` tags and later, when it found closing tags, he dt find opening tags (cause he autoclose them) and add opening `<p>` tag to this two closing `</p>` tags. But ok, i'll search in this direction, maybe there are strange symbols, which force browser to do this

Answer (score 2):

Firebug shows the real generated code in the browser. This might differ (corrected, slightly altered) from the html sent from your server.

There are 3 steps:

1. Your server code
2. The generated html
3. What your browser makes of it (= what you see in firebug)

Comment: yes, and i think trouble is in step 3 (cause generated html is correct). But i can't understand why browser convets 2 of my `<p>` tags and 2 of my closing `</p>` tags to `<p></p>` combination :(

Comment: because according to html standards, a P tag must always be closed or have a closing tag.

Comment: they're closed, i have code like that: `<p><p>SOMETHING</p></p>` and it have changed to `<p></p><p></p>SOMETHING<p></p><p></p>`. maybe there are strange symbols at beginning of `SOMETHING` part, which force browser to autoclose my P tags... i'll check it

Answer (score 0):

Firebug displays the source corrected. This means it adds missing tags. The proper way to see the real html is "see source html" in your browser.

Comment: i put real html in top of my question - it have 2 open P tags. I can't underastand why browser closes them just after beginning tag. BTW, closing tag of this P is also changes to `<p></p>` combination

Answer (score 0):

While it is technically ok to have open `<p>` tags, my guess is the browser auto-closes them when encountering the next block tag. Use `<br/>` tags to add line breaks, or add text to your `<p>` nodes.

The browser can deal with input like:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum
<p>Foobar text
```

And will automatically interpret it as if it read

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Foobar text</p>
```

Thus, your code

```
<div>
<p><p>
<div> ....
```

becomes:

```
<div>
<p></p><p></p>
<div> ....
```

Try set a HTML doctype and stick with the html/xml rules for it. Make your html error free and test it with [the w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/). As a rule of thumb, don't use `<p>` tags without closing them, and don't wrap them around other block tags either.